# how to determine if UIScrollView flicks to next page when paging

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I use UIScrollView to display lots of images. for memory issue, i only load three images at a time. when user flick to the next(or previous), i will shift two images and load a new one.

firstly, i use scrollViewDidEndDecelerating methord to determine whether UIScrollView change to next page , previous page or still the current. But when you flick quickly and continuously, scrollViewDidEndDecelerating methord will not receive any message,which means not be called, while scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate still receive the message. because the dragging is so quick that the previous decelerating be ignored.

So I wonder where can i know whether the view will change and how to judge the changes when i flick quickly? in scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate methord or some other ways?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't rely on the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` method but will implement the  `scrollViewDidScroll` protocol and update the page when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible:

```
CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.bounds.size.width;
int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1; 
self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
```

**EDIT**

Page control combine with scroll view are well explained in this [tut](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/)

Comment: i will have a try. i see this method at pagecontrol sample. the method is called so frequent that confuse me.

Comment: also do you just want to set the new page when scrolling or detect the change in page only (I should edit my answer then)

Comment: i will load a new one and shift two images.

Comment: why you don't shift 3 images since you have 3 images per page?

Comment: also you might want to consider GMGridView(https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView). This is a well written lib for grid support. They handle paging.

Comment: i put one image to one page.when turning pages. i will remove the first and last, then shift the two others and load a new one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15489/discussion-between-chancy-and-tiguero)

Comment: i can turn page in scrollViewDidScroll, but when i shift the two image and load a new one,then i use scrollRectToVisible to move the visible Rect, its not smooth and natural. but if i do the work in scrollViewDidEndDecelerating. there is no such problem. do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollViewl
{
  tempPageNO=PageNo;
  CGFloat pageWidth = scrollViewl.frame.size.width;
  int f=((scrollViewl.contentOffset.x-pageWidth/2)/pageWidth)+1;

  //----------newPageNo----------------
  PageNo=f;

  if (tempPageNO!=PageNo) {
    NSLog(@"it's true when page is changed.");
    NSLog(@"page NO %i",PageNo);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 version of tiguero's answer. Hoping it'll save someone 0.5 minutes.

```
let pageWidth = scrollView.bounds.size.width
let page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1
self.pageControl.currentPage = Int(page)
```